# Equal vertical spacing between quote and chapter number independent of line spacing

Tags: formatting, quotchap

Similar to the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565988/making-a-small-modification-to-a-latex-environment) question on stackoverflow, I have renewed the `\begin{savequote}` and `\end{savequote}` environment to be always single spaced no matter what the rest of the document is.

However, the use of `\doublespace` creates a tremendous extra space between the quote and chapter number, as seen in the following figure.

[image]

How can I make sure that the spacing between the quote and chapter number is always the same, no matter what spacing is used for the document?

For the image I used the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage{setspace}


\makeatletter
\let\oldquote\savequote
\def\savequote{\@ifnextchar[\savequote@i \savequote@ii}
\def\savequote@i[#1]{\oldquote[#1]\singlespace}
\def\savequote@ii{\oldquote\singlespace}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\doublespace

\mainmatter

\begin{savequote}[10pc]
\sffamily There is always something to say, in nice quote boxes, that spans more than one line.
\qauthor{Some person}
\end{savequote} 

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redefining the innards of the `savequote` environment directly, I would load the `etoolbox` package and use its `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `AfterEndEnvironment` macros to place the material of the entire `savequote` environment inside a `singlespace` environment. Do distinguish between the environment versions of the macros of the `setspace` package (e.g., `singlespace`) and the package's direct macros (e.g., `\singlespacing`, `\doublespacing`).

To assure that the vertical distance between the top of the page and the chapter header, as well as between the chapter header and the chapter's body, is not affected by `\doublespacing`, the LaTeX macros `\chapter`, `\@chapter`, and `\@schapter` need to be modified. This can be achieved directly, as is done in the code below, or with the help of a package such as `titlesec`.

The modified MWE thus might look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,quotchap,setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{savequote}{\begin{singlespace}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{savequote}{\end{singlespace}}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\begin{singlespace}}{}{}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\end{singlespace}\nointerlineskip}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@schapter}{\end{singlespace}\nointerlineskip}{}{}
\makeatother         

\begin{document}
\doublespacing

\mainmatter

\begin{savequote}[10pc]
\sffamily There is always something to say, in nice quote boxes, that spans more than one line.
\qauthor{Some person}
\end{savequote} 

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the etoolbox option, I'm not that familiar with redefining things... However, even though your suggestion might be better than my redefinition, the spacing issue remains.

Comment: @DoubleYou - There are two, not just one, spacing issues. I thought earlier that you were referring just to the one affecting the line spacing above the `savequote` environment. Are you also looking to fix the (entirely separate) issue of the vertical distance between the top of the page and the start of the chapter header?

Comment: Even though I might have not provided the right way of redefining the savequote, from the image you can see that even with my option the quote line spacing is always singlespaced. So I thought to have solved one spacing option myself, and the other spacing issue I don't know how to solve is the vertical space between the quote and the chapter number.

Comment: @DoubleYou - I've modified the code so that the chapter header material is also typeset in singlespacing mode, regardless of the overall spacing settings that may be in effect.